# Sumarize many columns by treatment

Tags: r, multiple-columns, summarize

I have a large data set with many columns and I am trying to find the mean and st of each column per treatment.

*Example data*

| treatment | age | experience | grade | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 21 | 3 | 4 | 0,7 |
| a | 24 | 4 | 4 | 0,5 |
| b | 32 | 12 | 5 | 0,6 |
| b | 54 | 23 | 3 | 0,7 |
| c | 15 | 1 | 4 | 0,9 |
| c | 19 | 3 | 5 | 0,4 |

I tried:

```
db%>%
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(age),sd=sd(age), .groups = "drop")
```

Is there a way to summarise all the columns without adding them individually? (my dataset has 56 columns)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try `db %>% group_by(treatment) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), list(Mean = mean, SD = sd)))`

Comment: Thank both that the link was very helpful to understand the next step that I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(across(1:3, 
                ~sd(.), .names = '{col}_sd'),
            across(1:3, 
                ~mean(.), .names = '{col}_mean'))
```